# How can i change specific dates background color in Android CalendarView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-calendar, calendarview

In my app i display statistics of tasks which user complete weekly. I want display it on calendar. Each task have own date. I want to make the days backgrounds green when the tasks are done or red when the tasks aren't done. I just need to learn how can i change spesific dates background on calendar view.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, `CalendarView` does not support that. However, there are [lots of third-party calendar libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=calendar), some of which may support your desired feature.

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you know which one is best for me?

Comment: No, as I have not evaluated them, let alone for your specific criteria.